# Calling events withing KeyUp and KeyDown Event VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, keyboard

I've developed a call to an event using the `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` events of a control.

The events `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` of the control are called properly.

But the RaiseEvent instruction doesn't raise an event.

The same event on a different part of code is called properly.

Does anyone know if is possible to call other events within a `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` event?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know if is possible to call other events within a KeyUp and KeyDown event?

Yes, it is possible.

It's called cascading events. Here's an interesting article on it: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventCollaboration.html#eventcascade

To help us better diagnose your issue, please provide some code samples.